# Difference between cancelling a connection and setting it to nil

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

In iOS I am using NSURLConnection -

```
NSURLConnection *aConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc....
```

is there a difference between:

```
[aConnection cancel];
```

and

```
aConnection = nil;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send the connection a `cancel` message, it will stop to invoke your delegates as soon as possible and tear down the connection.

Note: it *may* happen in rare cases that you still get one already queued delegate message *other than* `connection:didFailWithError:` after you send `cancel` from a different tread than the one the connection schedules delegates.

With setting your reference to the connection to `nil`, you simply do this. This does not cancel the connection - and if this was your only reference, you also can't send a cancel anymore. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically by doing this:

```
aConnection = nil;
```

you cannot be sure that there are no other references to this object. So you should do this:

```
[aConnection cancel];
```

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I was trying to show the whole concept, not the NSURLConnection case only why should use the object's API to control the object but not just nullify the reference

Comment: I too believe you meant the right thing and implicitly assumed to OP wanted to cancel - but it was a bit too unclear ;)